# An optional parameter must be a reference type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It is a couple days since I am trying to find what is the problem with my code. I need to create such dynamic links in my project: ParentCategory (Category) - ChildCategory (SubCategory) - Pages (Pages List) - PageDetails (page details by id).

I created ParentCategory and ChildCategory list successfully, both are dynamic, but when I press to go to Pages, this error appears:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetPages(Int32)' in
>   'bandymas.Controllers.PageController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameter name: parameters

My PageViewModels looks like this:

```
 public class Page
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ShortDescription")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Meta")]
        public string Meta { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UrlSeo")]
        public string UrlSeo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User Image")]
        public string UserImage { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Experience")]
        public int Exp { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Logo")]
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Website URL")]
        public string WebURL { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Facebook URL")]
        public string FacebookUrl { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public int ChildCategoryId { get; set; }



    }

    public class ParentCategory
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Parent Category Name")]
        public string PCatName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UrlSeo")]
        public string UrlSeo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ChildCategory> ChildCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildCategory
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Parent Category Name")]
        public string CCatName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UrlSeo")]
        public string UrlSeo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my PageRepository

```
public IList<ParentCategory> GetParentCategories()
    {
        return _context.ParentCategories.ToList();
    }

    public IList<ChildCategory> GetChildCategories(int Id)
    {
        return _context.ChildCategories.Where(category => category.ParentCategoryId == Id).ToList();
    }

    public IList<Page> GetPages(int Id)

    {
        return _context.Pages.Where(x => x.ChildCategoryId == Id).ToList();
    }
```

And PageController

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var pcategories = _pageRepository.GetParentCategories();
        return View(pcategories);
    }

    public ActionResult GetChildCategories(int ParentCategoryId)
    {
        var ccategories = _pageRepository.GetChildCategories(ParentCategoryId);
        return View(ccategories);
    }

    public ActionResult GetPages(int Id)
    {

        var pages = _pageRepository.GetPages(Id);
        foreach (var page in pages)
        {


            page.ChildCategoryId = Id;
            page.UserName = page.UserName;
            page.City = page.UserImage;
            page.Address = page.City;
            page.PhoneNumber = page.Body;
        }
            return View(pages);
    }
```

Here is GetChildCategories View

```
@using bandymas.Models
@using bandymas.Controllers

<div style="font-family:Arial">
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetChildCategories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>GetChildCategories</h2>
<h2>Child Categories List</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (PageViewModels.ChildCategory ccategory in @Model)
    {
        <li>
           @Html.ActionLink(ccategory.CCatName, "GetPages", "Page",
new { ChildCategoryId = ccategory.Id }, null)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
</div>
```

And Here Is GetPagesView

```
@using bandymas.Models
```

@using bandymas.Controllers

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetPages";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@*@Html.BeginForm("GetPages", "Page",new { Id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Get, null)*@
@foreach (var page in Model)
{



<div style="font-family:Arial">
    <h2>GetPages</h2>

    <h2>Pages List</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="hidden" name="@page.Id" value="@page.Id" /></li>
        <li>
            @page.UserName
        </li>
        <li>
            @page.City
        </li>
        <li>
            @page.Address
        </li>
        <li>
            @page.PhoneNumber
        </li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Back to ChildCategories List", "GetChildCategories", new { departmentId = @Model.DepartmentId })  </li>
    </ul>
</div>

}
```

This optional parameter error appears when I go to GetPages View from GetChildCategories View. I tried to change optional parameter in RouteConfig.cs and add int? next to Id,but it is still not working...

Comment: Perhaps you could just change `GetPages(int Id)` to `GetPages(int? Id)` ? If your view send `null` then action method should accept `nullable` parameter, not `valuetype` as `int` cannot be `null` indeed. So use nullable int instead (int?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PageController's ActionResult parameter name as to match with the name which you have given in the action link i.e,

@Html.ActionLink("Back to ChildCategories List", "GetChildCategories", new { **departmentId** = @Model.DepartmentId }) which is of GetPagesView.

@Html.ActionLink(ccategory.CCatName, "GetPages", "Page",new { **ChildCategoryId** = ccategory.Id }, null) in GetChildCategoriesView.

Because of the mismatch of the parameter names you were receiving that error..The name as to be same like the one which you give in the Actionlink..Your pagecontroller as to be like this..

PageController:

```
public ActionResult GetChildCategories(int departmentId)
{
    var ccategories = _pageRepository.GetChildCategories(departmentId);
    return View(ccategories);
}


public ActionResult GetPages(int childCategoryId)
{

    var pages = _pageRepository.GetPages(childCategoryId);
    foreach (var page in pages)
    {


        page.ChildCategoryId = childCategoryId;
        page.UserName = page.UserName;
        page.City = page.UserImage;
        page.Address = page.City;
        page.PhoneNumber = page.Body;
    }
        return View(pages);
}
```